# Return a JSON array from a Controller in Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am trying return a JSON response from a controller in Symfony 2. Form example, in Spring MVC I can get a JSON response with @ResponseBody annotattion. I want get a JSON response, no mtter if it is a JSON Array or a Json Object, then, manipulate it with javascript in the view.

I try the next code:

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *      "/drop/getCategory/",
     *      name="getCategory"
     * )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function getAllCategoryAction() {
        $categorias = $this->getDoctrine()
                           ->getRepository('AppBundle:Categoria')
                           ->findAll();

        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData($categorias);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
```

But I get `[{},{}]` as Response in the browser. I try with `$response = new Response(json_encode($categorias));` too, but I get the same result.

Comment: Did you try 'return new JSONResponse($data);'?

Comment: $categorias is an object. but setData expects an array.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to do this (based on previous answer):

```
public function getAllCategoryAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT c
        FROM AppBundle:Categoria c'
    );
    $categorias = $query->getArrayResult();

    return new JsonResponse($categorias);
}
```

It works perfect with any Query that Doctrine returns as array.

Comment: You can improve your answer by using `JsonResponse` instead of `Response`. This will avoid duplicate uses of `json_encode` and custom headers.

Answer (score 26):

I think the @darkangelo answer need explainations.

The `findAll()` method return a collection of objects.

```
$categorias = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Categoria')
                   ->findAll();
```

To build your response, you have to add all getters of your entities to your response like :

```
$arrayCollection = array();

foreach($categorias as $item) {
     $arrayCollection[] = array(
         'id' => $item->getId(),
         // ... Same for each property you want
     );
}

return new JsonResponse($arrayCollection);
```

Use `QueryBuilder` allows you to return results as arrays containing all properties :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT c
    FROM AppBundle:Categoria c'
);
$categorias = $query->getArrayResult();

return new JsonResponse($categorias);
```

The `getArrayResult()` avoids need of getters.

Answer (score 6):

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/list", name="list")
 */
public function getList(SerializerInterface $serializer, SomeRepository $repo): JsonResponse
{
    $models = $repo->findAll();
    $data = $serializer->serialize($models, JsonEncoder::FORMAT);
    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK, [], true);
}
```

Comment: as explain at https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html add `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;`, I should add also `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;`

Answer (score 2):

Following the best practices, I managed to do it the following way:

```
public function index(CityRepository $cityRepository,
                      SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
```

Injecting repository & serializer.

```
$cities = $cityRepository->findAll();
```

Retrieving an array of objects.

```
$data = $serializer->serialize($cities, 'json');
```

Serializing the data into a JSON string.

```
return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
```

Passing the JSON string to `JsonResponse`.

Comment: I get very ugly object "{\u0022id\u0022:105,\u0022name\u0022:\u00223..." how to fix it ?

Comment: @ArturO The serializer in this example returns a JSON string; check that the `JsonResponse` has the last parameter set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code this way:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/drop/getCategory/",
 *      name="getCategory"
 * )
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getAllCategoryAction() {
    $categorias = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getRepository('AppBundle:Categoria')
                       ->findAll();

    $categorias = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($categorias, 'json');

    $response = new Response($categorias);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

If the `serializer` service is not enabled, you have to enable it in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
    framework:
        # ...
        serializer:
            enabled: true
```

For more advanced options for serialization, you can install [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)

Comment: I get a 500 error: You have requested a non-existent service "serializer".

Comment: You have to enable first the serializer service. In app/config/config.yml add this:
`framework:
    # ...
    serializer:
        enabled: true`

Comment: I get the solution:

$categorias = $query->getArrayResult();

  //$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  //return $response;
  //return $this->render('AppBundle:Front:test.html.twig', array('otra' => $otra));
  return new Response(json_encode($categorias), 200);

Comment: That's a good solution too. Didn't work using the `serializer` service? I find to be a better practice to use a serializer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to put into response a collection. For that you need to setup serializer (or retrieve data as an array).

Look at this doc pages: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

and

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  the following solution:

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *      "/drop/getCategory/",
     *      name="getCategory"
     * )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function getAllCategoryAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
            FROM AppBundle:Categoria c'
        );
        $categorias = $query->getArrayResult();


        return new Response(json_encode($categorias), 200);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use newJsonResponse like you did in your question.