# Symfony3 how to bind an array with Doctrine 2

Tags: arrays, doctrine-orm, bind, symfony-3.3

I have an array `$brands` as parameter of my repository function `public function getBrandsByFilter($brands)`. I rescue this array from an ajax `POST` method and it looks like at :

```
$brands = ["brand"  
    [
      "caporal" => "caporal"
      "adidas" => "adidas"
    ]
]
```

I'd like to pass each values (caporal, adidas) of my array as arguments of my `WHERE` query clause of my repository but I have this exception :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT a0_.brand AS brand_0 FROM article a0_ WHERE a0_.brand IN (?, ?) GROUP BY a0_.brand' with params ["caporal", "adidas"]:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Here is my repository `ArticleRepository.php` :

```
 public function getBrandsByFilter($brands)
 {
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
     $qb
         ->select('a')
         ->andWhere('a.brand IN (:brandFilter)')
         ->setParameter('brandFilter', $brands, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);

     return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 }
```

### UPDATE : THIS ISSUE IS RESOLVED, IT CAME OF THE WRONG FORMAT OF THE ARRAY AS SAID IN THE COMMENTS. BUT ON THE OTHER SIDE I HAVE A NEW FOLLOWING PROBLEM.

In my controller I retrieve well the result of my query `getBrandsByFilter()` but I don't get to send it in a `jsonResponse()`toward `Ajax`.

Here is my `controller` code :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/ajax/request", options={"expose"=true}, name="ajax_request")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function ajaxRequestAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $brands = $request->request->get('brand');

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArticleBundle:Article');

            /* I retrieve my query result */
            $articles = $repository->getBrandsByFilter($brands);

            /* And send it toward Ajax */
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            return $response->setData(array('data' => $articles));
        }
    }
```

And here my `ajax` function :

```
    $('#submitFilter').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: Routing.generate("ajax_request"),
            data: { brand: selectedBrand },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            // HERE I WANT RETRIEVE MY JsonRESPONSE
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log(data);

                for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                    Object.keys(data[i]).forEach(function (key) {
                        var propertyData = data[i][key];
                        //console.log(key);
                        //
                    })
                }
            });
    })
```

When I debug the `$articles` variable in my controller, I have an array of objects like this :

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => Article {#612 ▼
    -id: 203
    -fosUserId: null
    -name: "article 1"
    -category: "sous-vêtements"
    -brand: "caporal"
    -model: "running"
    -gender: "unisex"
  1 => Article {#610 ▶}
  2 => Article {#631 ▶}
  3 => Article {#619 ▶}
  4 => Article {#657 ▶}
  5 => Article {#635 ▶}
  6 => Article {#695 ▶}
  7 => Article {#633 ▶}
]
```

But when I debug `data` in my ajax I have an array of empty objects :

```
data: Array(8)
    0: {} 
    1: {}
    2: {}
    3: {}
    4: {}
    5: {}
    6: {}
    7: {}
```

I don't know why I retrieve an array of EMPTY objects while the one that I send in the JsonRESPONSE is filled. Thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution in an other issue wich unfortunately I have not seen before.

You have to replace `getResult` by `getArrayResult` to get an array well formatted of the query result. See the [solution of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34577422/5946854)

```
public function getBrandsByFilter($brands)
 {
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
     $qb
         ->select('a')
         ->andWhere('a.brand IN (:brandFilter)')
         ->setParameter('brandFilter', $brands, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);

     /* Here replace getResult() by getArrayResult() */
     return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
 }
```

And in teh controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajax/request", options={"expose"=true}, name="ajax_request")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function ajaxRequestAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $brands = $request->request->get('brand');

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArticleBundle:Article');

        $articles = $repository->getBrandsByFilter($brands);

        return new JsonResponse($articles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$brands` array the content should be in this way;

```
$brands = [
    ["caporal" => "caporal"], ["adidas" => "adidas"]
];
```

Or;

```
$brands = [
    ["caporal"], ["adidas"]
];
```

It will work but i think you should not use `->andWhere`, `->where` working this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's right, but I have a new issue, if you can take a look that will be great

Comment: hım, try it -> `return new JsonResponse(array('articles' => $articles));`
In addition, you added `@Method({"POST"})`, so no need to check `if ($request->isMethod('post'))`

Comment: I've already tried that but no change .. I have the impression it's the array of articles objects who's problematic