# Empty objects JsonResponse

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine

I would like to return a JsonResponse of all my articles from my database, I have articles in my database but I get empty objects, I do not know why..

This is the result of the dump of my articles :

[image]

And the JsonResponse :

[image]

The code of my controller :

```
    /**
 * @Route("/api/all-articles", name="sg_api_liste_articles")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function getListArticles()
{
    $articles = $this->entityManager->getRepository('SGBundle:Article')->findAll();

    return new JsonResponse($articles);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You need to convert the entities to arrays. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141192/return-a-json-array-from-a-controller-in-symfony

Comment: Great! You're welcome.